# How to Calculate Leading in PDF Document

Tags: pdf, spacing, leading-zero

How do I calculate leading in a PDF document?

For example:

```
48 0 0 48 72 677.28 Tm
(Hello World) Tj
0 -1.1075 TD
```

This renders the text **Hello World** at 48pt/57.6pt (120% line height) in `Times-Roman`.

According to the [PDF Reference](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference13.pdf) manual, "the leading parameter is measured in unscaled text space units. It specifies the vertical distance between the baselines of adjacent lines of text... The number is expressed in thousandths of a unit of text space."

Can someone please explain how `1.1075` and `57.6` are related?

Comment: Where did you get the 120% from and why do you multiply it with 48 to get the 57.6? The Tm operator scales the font size (set by Tf) with 48 but your piece of code does not show the operands of the Tf operator.

Comment: The text is single-spaced (120%). The font is of `Type 1` and it is not embedded. The `1.1075` appears to be related to the height identified in its metrics file: `FontBBox -167 -229 1009 878` Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You pdf commands is incorrect. I suppose you mean:

```
48 0 0 48 72 677.28 Tm
0 -1.1075 TD    
(Hello World) Tj
```

This code set text coordinate system to (Tm command):

```
Scale x48 on x and x48 on y 
Start position (72, 677.28)
```

Then it's move position to next line. Next line in 1.1075 "**text**" pixels. And then move start position by -1.1075 "**text**" pixels on y coordinate. Text pixel in this example it's pdf pixel multiplyed by 48. It's set by Tm command.

I may simplify you PDF code. It's the same:

```
48 0 0 48 72 570.096 Tm
(Hello World) Tj
```

Explanation: 677.28 - (1.1075*48) - (1.1075*48)

YOU should always remember that PDF it's a language. To calculate the real coordinates you shoud parse all previous commands. 
There may be something like this before you commands:

```
10 0 0 10 0 0 cm
```

Answer (score -1):

The leading is usually set in the PDF by the command TL, just like this:

```
12 TL
(El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha)'
```

That 12 indicates a leading of 12 points until another TL is found.

I hope it helps you. I think this is the easiest way to do it :)

Comment: *That 12 indicates a leading of 12 points* - unless transformation matrices change the rules.